# PHP handling the addition of a class to an HTML element

Tags: php, html

I need to achieve the following:
I have a php file responsible for sending my form. Everything works fine but I want php to add the class active to a div in my HTML so that a popup of message sent can be displayed on the page to the user.
Here's my html:

```
<div class="sentMessage">
    <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
    <p>Thank you! Your message has been successfully sent.</p>
</div>
```

this is my php script at the moment:

```
if ($sending) {
    // If the message is sent I output a string to use it  
    echo "SENDING"; 
}
```

what I want - instead of outputting the SENDING msg - is to add the class active so that my div looks like this:

```
<div class="sentMessage active">
    <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
    <p>Thank you! Your message has been successfully sent.</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be extremly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the PHP is responsible for drawing the html code for that `<div>` you could just have it add the "active" when it does so. For that matter, you could just have it only draw the div if your conditions are met. It may be that you need to add more detail for a more useful answer.

Comment: Assuming this HTML code is in the same script file, something basic like `<div class="sentMessage <?php echo $sending ? 'active' : ''; ?>">` should do it. Using the ternary operator here, but an actual `if` could of course also be used in that place. If you don’t know basics such as how to switch between HTML and PHP, then you should go read up on them - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @CBroe my html code is in my index external to PHP script. My problem is that I don't know how to target an html element in PHP like I would do in JavaScript with document.getElement or document.querySelector. Can you help me please?

Comment: _“My problem is that I don't know how to target an html element in PHP like I would do in JavaScript with document.getElement or document.querySelector.”_ - you wouldn’t, not a situation like this, because that makes rather little sense (you would have to use a DOM parser to parse your HTML into something PHP can work with first of all.) _“my html code is in my index external to PHP script”_ - so how would your `$sending` variable get from your PHP script to whatever file contains your HTML code in the first place? Is your “index” a static HTML file? It should be made into a script then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a condition in a div...

```
<div class="sentMessage <?php echo $sending ? 'active' : '' ?>">
    <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
    <p>Thank you! Your message has been successfully sent.</p>
</div>
```

We don't know where `$sending` is defined, you should check if it exists first (`isset`, or `!empty`). Than it'd be

```
<div class="sentMessage <?php echo !empty($sending) ? 'active' : '' ?>">
```